# How to get a difference between two cursor positions at the two different moment?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have a one position of cursor, I put it in a some variable, and I want get a difference between this variable and cursor position after 10 ms. I have no idea what to do.

I want to make a such drag'n'drop where might drag the element without focusing concretely it. All what I'm could do here, but it's bullshit, but may be it help you to understand what I actually want)).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>example</title>
    <style>
    .red {
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
        cursor: move;
    position:relative;
}

.green {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}

    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var draggble = false;
var currentLeft;
var currentX;

$(document).on("mousedown",".red",function(){
    draggble = true;
    currentLeft = parseInt($(".green").css("left"),10);
});

$(document).on("mouseup", "body", function () {
        draggble = false;
});

$(document).on("mousemove","body",function(e){
    currentX = e.pageX;
    if(draggble){
        setTimeout(function(){
        currentLeft = currentLeft + currentX - e.pageX;
        $(".green").css("left",currentLeft);      
    },10);
    }
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="red">
    <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f8Kx9/

I'm also sorry for my awful English, it's almost first time when I need to write.